# How to group mean center several columns at the same time?

Tags: r

I have no prolem doing group-mean centering for one variable at a time but how can I do that for multiple variables at the same time?

```
library(misty)
x<-(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1))
y<-(c(1, NA, 3, 5, 3, 2))
group<-as.factor(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1))
mydata<-data.frame(x, y, group)
mydata<-mydata%>% mutate(x_cwc = center(mydata$x, type="CWC", group=mydata$group))
mydata<-mydata%>% mutate(y_cwc = center(mydata$y, type="CWC", group=mydata$group))
```

Comment: The way to use the same function on multiple columns is `across()`: `mydata %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~center(.x, type="CWC", group=group))`

Comment: Thanks!! But my R studio can't find the function across??

Comment: @jenny the queen. use the dplyr package

Comment: If you have `mutate()` but not `across()` you must be using an older version of `dplyr`. I'd suggest updating your dplyr or you could look into using the `mutate_all` or `mutate_each` functions.

Comment: My previous answer is wrong. This is correct: `mutate(across(a:z, ~center(.x, type="CWC", group=group))`