# How to group mean center variables and create a new column?

Tags: r, mutate

I've tried to compute group-mean in survey dataset, and create create new column (want to keep the original variables).

I found this post is really useful

[How to group mean center several columns at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993458/how-to-group-mean-center-several-columns-at-the-same-time)

```
mutate(across(a:z, ~center(.x, type="CWC", group=group))
```

I also found another code, though it's about grand mean centering.

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = colnames(mydata)[56:58], 
            .funs = list("z" = scale))
```

But how can I make new columns with different names based on any of those codes?

Comment: (1) `mutate_at` is superseded, I think you should stick with the first method using `across`. (2) Please be explicit about which non-base packages you're using. I'm inferring `dplyr`, so that tag should be _added_ (`mutate` is not very helpful here), but it isn't clear where `center` is defined. (3) Sample data would be useful.

Comment: Best is to provide a concrete example of a data frame showing what you have, and then also what you want as the output.